# How to Config NGINX as api gateway When using Zookeeper registry

Tags: nginx, spring-cloud-zookeeper

how to config nginx read dynamic service when service registry zookeeper.
sorry for my bad English

in application.yml.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    zookeeper:
      connect-string: localhost:2181
```

in file api_gateway.conf i have upstream:

```
upstream user_server {
  least_conn;
  server 192.168.0.111:8080;
  server 192.168.0.112:8080;
}

upstream email_server {
  least_conn;
  server 192.168.0.111:8081;
  server 192.168.0.112:8081;
}
```

in nginx.conf i include api_gateway.conf and use

```
location /auth {
      proxy_pass http://user_server;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

    # config server email
  location /email {
      proxy_pass http://email_server;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

it succeeds. but i want nginx read ip and port from zookeeper discovery as like spring cloud gateway and spring eureka.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry. I added the code